# Starting a java project that uses Rapid miner

Tags: java, eclipse, rapidminer

I was asked to develop a project that will use Rapidminer library from which i will provide a interface to view results in some graphical form,. i am NOT an advanced programmer but can work around with codes.

i have included all packages, libraries and necessary jars in my project, that i am building using eclipse.

referring some sites and codes from internet, i have started integration of Rapidminer in my program, but FAILED to do so.

please guide me to start my project, or any good source from internet where i can learn and be able to develop my project from scratch.

i have seen Rapidminer blogs and web, but i am NOT able to understand thing properly..

Thanx...for your help and precious time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok lets start here. you should first prepare the domain you need to mine, and generate patterns or knowledge, after that you have to decide which way you have to show those data - web or standalone. and then you simply need to start...